# BigO sorting complexity help

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Given a bit sequence of length a, what is the minimum number of comparisons needed to determine if it contains a pair of consecutive 1's in BigO notation

Answer (score 2):

Without any further information about the sequence, the complexity is $\mathcal{O}(n)$:
You have to look at least at every third bit (this is a loose lower bound, obviously, you cannot jump over more than 1 without the possibility of missing a "11". However, there is a $\mathcal{O}(n)$ algorithm:

```
for(i=0; i<a; i++)
    if(a(i)==1 && a(i+1)==1)return true
return false
```

Therefore, the best possible asymptotical behaviour is between $\Omega(\frac{1}{2}n)=\Omega(n)$ and $\mathcal{O}(2n)=\mathcal{O}(n)$, e.g. it is $\Theta(n)$.

Comment: Why can one jump 2 consecutive bits without reading them?

Comment: @Did Good job on reading my posting. I wrote can NOT jump

Comment: Yes, but you can't jump over more than *one* without the possibility of missing a "11".

Comment: @mrf does that do any difference whatsoever?

Comment: Yes: the difference it makes is that $\frac13n$ is misleading. But true enough, it is entirely up to you to decide if you want to help the reader to understand what it is that you are saying, or not.

Comment: Your lower bound is invalid (though it has the right $\mathcal{O}$).

Comment: @mrf It is not the largest lower bound, it is A lower bound. Therefore, my argument is correct.

Comment: Here is another lower bound: 42 (valid for every large enough $n$). "Therefore, my argument is correct."

Comment: @Did no, because $\mathcal{O}(1)\neq\mathcal{O}(n)$. Seriously now?

Comment: The lower bound 42 is incorrect? Seriously now, why don't you use the valid remarks made to you, to transform your answer into something sensible? To modify one's post is not a shame, you know...

Comment: @CBenni: Why not just change it to "every second bit" and "jump over more than 1" such that your agument will actually make intuitive sense instead of depend on a pointless arbitrarily _weakening_ which there's no reason to make (no matter that you're formally allowed do do it)?

Comment: @CBenni: Every function that is $\mathcal O(1)$ as $n\to\infty$ is also $\mathcal O(n)$. This fact is conventionally notated $O(1)=O(n)$. Yes, seriously.

Comment: I have finally understood what your problem was. I edited my post to use $\Omega(n)$ instead of $O(n)$. Is it correct now?

Comment: @CBenni: $\Omega$ is indeed more correct, but that is not the main problem Did and mrf and I pointed out. Your edit still leaves the strange pointless choice of "every third bit"/"jump over more than 2" in there instead of the intuitively reasonable "every second bit" and "jump over more than 1".

Comment: @HenningMakholm well, I figured argumenting that you cannot jump over 1 is harder to argue, because you can jump over every other element and then only check if necessary. 1/3n is fail-safe. If you absolutely wish, I can edit my answer; I dont see any reason to yet.

Comment: @CBenni: The point is that you have to inspect _at least_ ever other bit, because if you _ever_ jump over two bits, those two bits could have been 11. I cannot imagine an argument for "you have to inspect at least every third bit" that isn't basically this plus "1/3 of the bits are even fewer than 1/2 of the bits, so that won't work either". That's not fail-safe, it's just a pointless weakening of the main argument. (There's no need to argue that inspecting $n/2$ bits will not work; only that inspecting _less than_ $n/2$ bits is incorrect).

Comment: @HenningMakholm but that does not change anything about the result, doesnt it? Therefore, this discussion is purely aesthetical... I will edit my answer nonetheless to please your needs.

Comment: @CBenni: No, it doesn't change anything about the result -- it just makes your argument for the result much harder to follow, because one has to figure out why you choose to go to the detour of mentioning 1/3 at all and reconstruct the implicit weakening you're doing, which doesn't buy you anything than increased obfuscation and confusion.

Comment: so for this case the specific answer would be O(1) rather than O(n)?

Comment: @user61620 no, the answer is O(n), dont let yourself get confused by the comments. They were just about the quality of my post. The post in the current state is valid.